# How to add Custom Menus to Google Sheet Addon

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-addon

My Google Sheet Addon is not Lunching the Custom Items, I want to show "Lunch" and "Create Template" Submenus in Example IN autoCart Addon we can see a lunch button (How to Achieve this )

Below i have attached the Sample script

[image]

```js
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e);
}

function onOpen(e) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Awesome Admin')
  
      .addItem('Launch Admin Console', 'showSidebar')
      .addItem('Create Tamplete', "newSheet")
      .addToUi();
}



function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
      .setTitle('G Suite Admin Console')
      .setWidth(400);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of createMenu use createAddonMenu()

Reference

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#menus_for_add-ons_in_google_sheets_docs_or_forms